# QCoreApplication quit not working

Tags: qt

I've created a console program. For debugging purposes, I need the program to quit if some conditions are not met. Here is an example:

```
if (VDD.isEmpty() || GND.isEmpty()){
    qWarning() << "VDD and GND must NOT be empty";
    QCoreApplication::quit();
    qWarning() << "After the quit";
}
```

As I understand it, the output after `quit()` should not be printed.

The `main()` function of my program is something like this:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);

    // Do stuff that calls the code above

    return a.exec();
}
```

Can anyone tell why this is happening?

For the time being I'm using `abort()`, but I would rather use `quit()`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`quit()` causes the event loop to return *when it next gets control*.  It will not return immediately.  So you'll need something like

```
QCoreApplication::quit();
return;
```

or possibly something a little more sophisticated if you're in a method that's not called directly from Qt.

The documentation of the related `exit()` method says:

> Note that unlike the C library function of the same name, this function *does* return to the caller -- it is event processing that stops.

Comment: Ahh. I get it. Then I'll just stick to abort. Thanks!

Comment: @aarelovich, unless you are handling `SIGABRT` signal, [`std::abort`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/program/abort) causes abnormal program termination. You are better using [`std::exit`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/program/exit). And if you just want to exit the application from within the main function, a single return statement will do the job. . .